# AWK modulo does not work correctly with trace file

Tags: awk

Using AWK, I am trying to parse a trace file like this:

```
s 5.072000000 _59_ AGT  --- 9 cbr 1000 [0 0 0 0] [energy 1994.974330 ei 5.011 es 0.000 et 0.001 er 0.014] ------- [59:0 0:0 32 0] [9] 0 0
r 5.072000000 _59_ RTR  --- 9 cbr 1000 [0 0 0 0] [energy 1994.974330 ei 5.011 es 0.000 et 0.001 er 0.014] ------- [59:0 0:0 32 0] [9] 0 0
s 5.080000000 _59_ AGT  --- 10 cbr 1000 [0 0 0 0] [energy 1994.974330 ei 5.011 es 0.000 et 0.001 er 0.014] ------- [59:0 0:0 32 0] [10] 0 0
r 5.080000000 _59_ RTR  --- 10 cbr 1000 [0 0 0 0] [energy 1994.974330 ei 5.011 es 0.000 et 0.001 er 0.014] ------- [59:0 0:0 32 0] [10] 0 0
s 5.088000000 _59_ AGT  --- 11 cbr 1000 [0 0 0 0] [energy 1994.974330 ei 5.011 es 0.000 et 0.001 er 0.014] ------- [59:0 0:0 32 0] [11] 0 0
r 5.088000000 _59_ RTR  --- 11 cbr 1000 [0 0 0 0] [energy 1994.974330 ei 5.011 es 0.000 et 0.001 er 0.014] ------- [59:0 0:0 32 0] [11] 0 0
s 5.096000000 _59_ AGT  --- 12 cbr 1000 [0 0 0 0] [energy 1994.974330 ei 5.011 es 0.000 et 0.001 er 0.014] ------- [59:0 0:0 32 0] [12] 0 0
r 5.096000000 _59_ RTR  --- 12 cbr 1000 [0 0 0 0] [energy 1994.974330 ei 5.011 es 0.000 et 0.001 er 0.014] ------- [59:0 0:0 32 0] [12] 0 0
s 5.104000000 _59_ AGT  --- 13 cbr 1000 [0 0 0 0] [energy 1994.974330 ei 5.011 es 0.000 et 0.001 er 0.014] ------- [59:0 0:0 32 0] [13] 0 0
r 5.104000000 _59_ RTR  --- 13 cbr 1000 [0 0 0 0] [energy 1994.974330 ei 5.011 es 0.000 et 0.001 er 0.014] ------- [59:0 0:0 32 0] [13] 0 0
s 5.112000000 _59_ AGT  --- 14 cbr 1000 [0 0 0 0] [energy 1994.974330 ei 5.011 es 0.000 et 0.001 er 0.014] ------- [59:0 0:0 32 0] [14] 0 0
r 5.112000000 _59_ RTR  --- 14 cbr 1000 [0 0 0 0] [energy 1994.974330 ei 5.011 es 0.000 et 0.001 er 0.014] ------- [59:0 0:0 32 0] [14] 0 0
s 5.120000000 _59_ AGT  --- 15 cbr 1000 [0 0 0 0] [energy 1994.974330 ei 5.011 es 0.000 et 0.001 er 0.014] ------- [59:0 0:0 32 0] [15] 0 0
r 5.120000000 _59_ RTR  --- 15 cbr 1000 [0 0 0 0] [energy 1994.974330 ei 5.011 es 0.000 et 0.001 er 0.014] ------- [59:0 0:0 32 0] [15] 0 0
s 5.128000000 _59_ AGT  --- 16 cbr 1000 [0 0 0 0] [energy 1994.974330 ei 5.011 es 0.000 et 0.001 er 0.014] ------- [59:0 0:0 32 0] [16] 0 0
r 5.128000000 _59_ RTR  --- 16 cbr 1000 [0 0 0 0] [energy 1994.974330 ei 5.011 es 0.000 et 0.001 er 0.014] ------- [59:0 0:0 32 0] [16] 0 0
s 5.136000000 _59_ AGT  --- 17 cbr 1000 [0 0 0 0] [energy 1994.974330 ei 5.011 es 0.000 et 0.001 er 0.014] ------- [59:0 0:0 32 0] [17] 0 0
r 5.136000000 _59_ RTR  --- 17 cbr 1000 [0 0 0 0] [energy 1994.974330 ei 5.011 es 0.000 et 0.001 er 0.014] ------- [59:0 0:0 32 0] [17] 0 0
s 5.144000000 _59_ AGT  --- 18 cbr 1000 [0 0 0 0] [energy 1994.974330 ei 5.011 es 0.000 et 0.001 er 0.014] ------- [59:0 0:0 32 0] [18] 0 0
r 5.144000000 _59_ RTR  --- 18 cbr 1000 [0 0 0 0] [energy 1994.974330 ei 5.011 es 0.000 et 0.001 er 0.014] ------- [59:0 0:0 32 0] [18] 0 0
s 5.152000000 _59_ AGT  --- 19 cbr 1000 [0 0 0 0] [energy 1994.974330 ei 5.011 es 0.000 et 0.001 er 0.014] ------- [59:0 0:0 32 0] [19] 0 0
r 5.152000000 _59_ RTR  --- 19 cbr 1000 [0 0 0 0] [energy 1994.974330 ei 5.011 es 0.000 et 0.001 er 0.014] ------- [59:0 0:0 32 0] [19] 0 0
s 5.160000000 _59_ AGT  --- 20 cbr 1000 [0 0 0 0] [energy 1994.974330 ei 5.011 es 0.000 et 0.001 er 0.014] ------- [59:0 0:0 32 0] [20] 0 0
r 5.160000000 _59_ RTR  --- 20 cbr 1000 [0 0 0 0] [energy 1994.974330 ei 5.011 es 0.000 et 0.001 er 0.014] ------- [59:0 0:0 32 0] [20] 0 0
s 5.168000000 _59_ AGT  --- 21 cbr 1000 [0 0 0 0] [energy 1994.974330 ei 5.011 es 0.000 et 0.001 er 0.014] ------- [59:0 0:0 32 0] [21] 0 0
r 5.168000000 _59_ RTR  --- 21 cbr 1000 [0 0 0 0] [energy 1994.974330 ei 5.011 es 0.000 et 0.001 er 0.014] ------- [59:0 0:0 32 0] [21] 0 0
s 5.176000000 _59_ AGT  --- 22 cbr 1000 [0 0 0 0] [energy 1994.974330 ei 5.011 es 0.000 et 0.001 er 0.014] ------- [59:0 0:0 32 0] [22] 0 0
r 5.176000000 _59_ RTR  --- 22 cbr 1000 [0 0 0 0] [energy 1994.974330 ei 5.011 es 0.000 et 0.001 er 0.014] ------- [59:0 0:0 32 0] [22] 0 0
```

's' and 'r' in column 1 denote 'send' and 'receive' respectively. Column 2 shows time. I want to run the following branch instruction on all lines and thereby calculate the delivery rate which is the percent ratio of `nRecvd/nSent*100`, but **between in 10-second intervals**. Next, I want to append time and delivery rate (in pair) for every interval to FILE so I can later use these pairs for plotting. However, the following AWK code does not give me any output. Where am I wrong?

```
BEGIN{
 nSent=0;
 nRecvd=0;
 nDropped=0;
 FILE="delivery.txt"
}

{
if ($1 == "s" && $4 == "AGT") nSent++;
else if ($1 =="r" && $4 == "AGT") nRecvd++;
else if ($1 =="D") nDropped++;
if ($1 == "r" && $4 =="AGT" && ($2 % 10) ==0) { 
 print $2 " " nSent/nReceived*100 "\n" >>FILE;
 nSent=0;
 nRecvd=0;
}

}

END {

}
```

Update:

Another part of the trace file is as follows:

```
r 10.103806919 _0_ AGT  --- 120 cbr 1020 [13a 0 21 800] ------- [33:0 0:0 30 0] [7] 1 0
s 10.104000000 _33_ AGT  --- 126 cbr 1000 [0 0 0 0] [energy 1989.895903 ei 9.962 es 0.000 et 0.076 er 0.066] ------- [33:0 0:0 32 0] [13] 0 0
r 10.104000000 _33_ RTR  --- 126 cbr 1000 [0 0 0 0] [energy 1989.895903 ei 9.962 es 0.000 et 0.076 er 0.066] ------- [33:0 0:0 32 0] [13] 0 0
s 10.104000000 _33_ RTR  --- 126 cbr 1020 [0 0 0 0] [energy 1989.895903 ei 9.962 es 0.000 et 0.076 er 0.066] ------- [33:0 0:0 30 0] [13] 0 0
r 10.104096612 _33_ MAC  --- 0 ACK 38 [0 21 0 0] [energy 1989.895903 ei 9.962 es 0.000 et 0.076 er 0.066] 
r 10.104114453 _14_ MAC  --- 0 AODV 48 [0 ffffffff f 800] [energy 1989.895886 ei 10.069 es 0.000 et 0.003 er 0.032] ------- [33:255 -1:255
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is because of your modulo. Indeed, in awk `1.00001 % 2 = 1.00001`. So if you never have a rounded time (i.e. X.0), your last if will never be true. Try using `int()`:

```
if ($1 == "r" && $4 =="AGT" && (int($2) % 10) == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `nReceived` in the printing rule which is never set/modified. So most likely that causes an error.

And on "`r`" lines in your example input `$4` is always "`RTR`" which results in a division by zero...

And next time please tell us, what is not working? No output? Error message?

Comment: I was getting no output. After applying @Shitsu's advice for casting to int now I receive a division by zero notice. Also, note that the actual trace file was too big too include here, so I just gave it partially.

Comment: Division by zero is explained in my answer above: you are trying to use `nReceived` as divisor but it's not existing at the time.

Comment: You are right. I mistakenly typed `nReceived` instead of `nRecvd`.